# Import Firebase analytics data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, firebase, mobile, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I will try to explain the context of the project on which I'm working and the problem which I currently try to overcome. 
 I would like to collect mobile data for analytics purpose, e.g. using Firebase from Google. After collecting thoses data, I'd like to store them in a local database, such as PostgreSQL or MongoDB. But the thing is mobile data collecting platform such as Firebase mostly doesn't support connecting to a local database. I've found out that there is a possibility to export raw data from Firebase to import into a local database, but I have no detail information about this. I've searched through many documentations and I couldn't find anything.
Has everyone ever had this kind of problem and can give a clear guidance about exporting data from Firebase and import into a local database? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics for Firebase collects enormous amount of data and send it to the servers in form of batches or bundles. Three things here with your design:

1. SDK collects that data and does not expose it for you to parse in the app and store it in local DB.
2. Storing this much data locally, you are going to re-invent the wheel. In addition, this could cause performance issues.
3. If you need all the data collected by Firebase in raw form, just [link Firebase to Big Query](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) and all data would be available to you.